# Docker deploy redis and node in my computer (Windows)

Tags: node.js, docker, redis

I want to deploy Docker stack with redis and node in my pc (Windows), but it is not working. But only node is working here.

```
web:
   # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
   image: usernmae/repo
   deploy:
   replicas: 5
   restart_policy:
    condition: on-failure
   resources:
    limits:
      cpus: "0.1"
      memory: 50M
   ports:
   - "3002:3002"
   networks:
   - webnet
visualizer:
   image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
   ports:
   - "8080:8080"
   volumes:
   - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
   deploy:
   placement:
    constraints: [node.role == manager]
   networks:
   - webnet
   redis:
        image: redis:alpine
        ports:
        - "6379:6379"
        volumes:
        - "/home/docker/data:/data"
        deploy:
         placement:
         constraints: [node.role == manager]
        command: redis-server --appendonly yes
        networks:
        - webnet
   networks:
        webnet:
```

This is my compose file. I don't understand what is going.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. "does not work" is not a helpful problem description. Please take the [tour] to understand how to ask a good question, then come back and [edit] yours. Include what you tried, what happened, and what you expected to happen instead. Any error messages? Stack traces?

Comment: Welcome to a world full of tears, pain and agony: Using docker on Windows.